# Deleting large number of rows from SQL Server - in an efficient and non-locking manner

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am writing a procedure to delete all rows from a few tables over n days old.

A dead simple query is easy to write

```
DELETE FROM [myTable] 
WHERE [Created] < GETDATE()-30
```

One problem is there is no index on the date field - I could add one, but I was working around it by doing something like:

```
SELECT @var = MAX([ID]) FROM myTable WHERE Created < GETDATE()-30; 
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE ID < @var
```

Does that seem like an acceptable method?

The problem is the table is huge, and this query will be deleting likely hundreds of thousands of rows every run.

Running it on a (slightly slow) test server it is taking an hour or so, and killing the table from other processes trying to read/write to it.

I don't so much mind it taking a while to run (though quicker is better) - but I can not have it locking the table for an hour while it is running, as there are constant read/writes going on (mainly writes).

My DB knowledge is quite basic, as I'm a coder not a dba.

Can someone give me a decent method for performing this task - in the most efficient way possible.

Comment: Why not simply select the records you will delete into a temp table, and then create a cursor to delete a couple records from the temp table in each run? Then you have a lot of small delete statements that shouldn't lock up your table.

Comment: Drop the old partition. If you don't have partitions, you should look into that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is a partitioned based sliding window: [How to Implement an Automatic Sliding Window in a Partitioned Table on SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). Partition the table by day and you can efficiently drop an entire day in a single partition switch operation at midnight. Partition switch is basically instantaneous.

If you want a solution with slightly lower overhead (partitioning has serious consequences and ripples through the entire application, specially when the indexes have to be aligned, which is a requirement for fast switch operations), then you have to design your schema in accordance with this operation. With 99.99% confidence I can say that the leftmost clustered key of your `myTable` *must* be the `Created` field. This would allow efficient batch deletes (`delete top (2500) from myTable where Created < ...`). There are many reasons why you want this to be batched (top 2500 or so at a time), most important being that you must avoid lock escalation and you must keep the size of any individual transaction within reasonable limits.

Answer (score 3):

Your method will suffer from the same malady as a normal delete would - you don't have an index on [Created]. Therefore your method is just more convoluted.

I would suggest that you create said index and try the normal delete on your test server.

Another suggestion - run this outside of normal business hours through a scheduler.

Answer (score 3):

To improve performance, you should look at creating an index on the Created field if this is something that you want to do often.

Then you could use

```
DELETE FROM myTable 
WHERE Created < GETDATE()-30
```

I've seen multi-hour processes reduced to mere seconds with the proper index and statistics addition.

Indexes are easy to create, and there could be tools available to suggest the index and provide the syntax. Example: SQL Tuning Advisor in MS SQL 2005 Management Studio.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that you cannot index the Created column (since that is the logical place to start otherwise).  Based upon that assumption, you are going to have performance and locking issues.  However, since you are using SQL 2005, you can take advantage of some new features specified in this article:
http://nayyeri.net/reduce-locks-for-delete-and-update-commands-in-sql-server-2005-with-top-clause

Basically, create a query that selects all of the records you want to affect.  Write the row identifiers (which are indexed) to a temp table.  Link the temp table to your table you want to delete from based upon the identifier.  Then use the batch delete specified here to delete groups at a time.

In this manner, you create a temp table based upon your date criteria (it won't be efficient because of the non-index but you can set NOLOCK on so it won't lock you up).  Then you delete the table in batches in order to reduce locking on the actual delete.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the index and performing the delete outside of office hours are probably the best things to do. However, if they aren't options, you could create a view based on your query and delete that view, thus only needing to reference the table once, rather than twice, speeding up IO operations.

```
create view v1 as (select * FROM myTable WHERE Created < GETDATE()-30;)
delete from v1
```

Comment: This would have zero effect.  With the exception of indexed views, when a view is used the view definition is expanded out and the query is run as normal (in very much the same way as it would be if you manually expanded out the view definition by hand).